# AWS::Serverless::Api | Cache key for any query string parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have created a Rest API that works as a proxy to a public URL. I have set the cache and noticed I have to configure the cacheKeyParameters for AWS to create the keys for caching.

I do not know beforehand what would be the query strings that the request may have. It could have `myapi?type=1` `myapi?search=terrain` or anything. I'm looking for a wildcard to be used here. How could I configure my proxy?

Here is my API definition:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  description: API as a proxy to public url
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  "/{proxy+}":
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses: {}
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        cacheKeyParameters: 
          - method.request.path.proxy
          - method.request.querystring.query # Here I need a wildcard for every query string
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: '200'
        requestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: method.request.path.proxy
        uri: 
          Fn::FindInMap : [EnvMap, Ref: Env, proxyUrl]
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: ANY
        type: http_proxy
```

Comment: It looks like this isn't possible at the moment.